# Exclude readme from Github pull request

Tags: git, github

I'm using Github and trying to create a pull request on someone else's project that I have forked. I edited the `Readme.md` in my fork, but I don't want them to get that commit.

How do I do that? It seems painfully simple but I cannot figure it out. Right now I've simply copypasted the original `Readme.md` back into my project and made the pull request, but that seems counterintuitive.

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is:

- make sure to create a branch from master, from a commit *before* your `README.md` modification ([typically, from `upstream/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646323/6309), with `upstream` being the name of the remote original repo that you forked)
- make your changes in that branch (which does not include the `README.md` modification)
- make your pull request from that dedicated branch (as recommended in "[couple tips for PR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)").

While you are adding your changes/fixes in that branch, you can modify whatever you want in your `master` branch, including the `README.md`.

Comment: Then pull the changes back into my master branch from the dedicated branch?

Comment: @NameMcChange no, a `master` should reflect the `master` of the original repo. You will rebase your `master` branch (with its modified `README.md`) on top of a fetched `upstream/master`, and that will include your PR commits if that PR was accepted and merged in the original repo.

Comment: Alright, I get it now. I don't like it, but I get it.