# How to configure the git that is used by TFS 2017 to merge a pull request?

Tags: git, tfs

For some reasons, I want to change the .gitconfig that is used by git when TFS tries to merge two branches during a Pull Request.

**Do you know a way to do that? Where is it?**

I use a private TFS version 15.117.26714.0.

For information, I want to set variables such as `diff.renameLimit`, `merge.renameLimit`, etc...

Comment: What impact would adding an `sslCAInfo` configuration option have on the merge?

Comment: I was just trying to fix an issue with Pull Requests, but finally it's not related to ssl certificates, so it's useless. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not change such setting in TFS sever side. And I also think this should not be the root cause of your previous issue  [How to debug "Pull request cannot be automatically merged." in TFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526383/how-to-debug-pull-request-cannot-be-automatically-merged-in-tfs/48540479?noredirect=1#48526383)

> Visual Studio allows you to configure and check some of the most
>   common Git configuration settings. **Global Settings** corresponds to
>   the **user-specific configuration file** and **Repository Settings**
>   corresponds to the repository-specific configuration file.
>
> Source Link:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/git-config?tabs=visual-studio#configuring-settings

Expect this there is no other setting. Your original issue should more related  account/branch / repository. To narrow down the issue, you could use another account to create a pull request.

Use another branch, repository to store the source and do the pull request.