# How to clean up GitHub pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-fork

I have created and edited a fork, and submitted a pull request. However, there are many commits on it and I would like to remove some of the irrelevant ones. How do I do this?

I have looked at many other answers (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream/9646323#9646323) one), but they all address slightly different problems, and as I am new to GitHub I don't know how to put them all together.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for squash, (interactive) rebase and force push. Just remove/edit the commits in your branch and do a force push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interactive rebase works generally, and is almost always a better solution (details [here](http://christoph-rumpel.com/2015/05/clean-up-your-commits-for-a-pull-request/)). However, I had problems with it and had to go about it a different way.

1) Re-cloning your fork to another location, something like:

```
git clone /your-username/your-repo
```

2) Restart your fork from upstream (details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream)):

```
git remote add upstream /url/to/original/repo
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master  
git push origin master --force`
```

3) Replace relevant files within repo and commit changes. After making your necessary changes again:

```
git commit -m "<commit message>"
git push origin <relevant-branch>
```

Hope this helps someone some time.

Answer (score -1):

For that you can goto the previous commit using

> `git checkout {commit_id}`
>   for commit id you can use 
>   `git log`

After that you can do new commit with your desired changes.

For further read [git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)
[Git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)