# What is the recommended way of getting the latest updates from upstream eleventy-base-blog into my forked blog?

Tags: git, rebase, eleventy

I have a blog based on a clone of the `eleventy-base-blog` [repo](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog). When I cloned it, I left the original code untouched in the `master` branch, and have made all my customisations and content changes in my own `blog` branch (so I could easily start from scratch by making a new branch from pristine `master`, if I made a mess of things).

Obviously I customise and make changes to my version, and over time it diverges from the upstream version, as well as from my local `master` branch.

I recently realised that I might be missing important bug fixes, improvements and new features from upstream, so I looked into how I could update my fork so as to keep up to date.

The answer I found, after much searching and trying to get clarity from all the range of advice out there ([1](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/keeping-a-github-fork-updated), [2](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#conceptual-overview), [3](https://gist.github.com/Chaser324/ce0505fbed06b947d962#keeping-your-fork-up-to-date)), seemed to be to use `git rebase`, so I tried doing:

```
git checkout master
git pull upstream master
git checkout blog
git rebase master
```

*([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39628366/5168907) suggests I should have done `fetch && reset --hard` instead of `pull`)*

but this ended up with a load of merge conflicts that I had to painstakingly wade through and manually fix. It seemed like my whole commit history needed yet another round of editing followed by

```
git rebase --continue
```

or whatever (see scenario #1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11219380/5168907)). I really don't want to have to do all that every time I want to get upstream updates. I didn't realise there would be so many conflicts.

So, what's a better way, if any, of getting a more seamless upgrade to the latest `eleventy-base-blog`, without having to manually preserve all my own customisations and edits? I feel like I am missing something, and it would be good to know how to do this better. Then I can maybe contribute a good updating procedure to be included in the docs for `eleventy-base-blog`.

Comment: If you and upstream both changed a particular line, the really isn't a way to avoid manual reconciliation. If you get conflicts in places you hadn't modified, something fundamental is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Some of the conflicts were where I had made edits - that makes sense, at least, though it would be lovely if there were a more user-friendly way of ignoring or accepting the changes... Other conflicts were in files like package-lock.json where all the lines with new file version numbers etc had to be accepted by me going through and manually editing out the older lines.

Comment: You can specify a specific merge strategy for those types of files, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/is-there-a-theirs-version-of-git-merge-s-ours

Comment: I just found this similar advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/39771096/5168907, as well the suggestion of `git mergetool` which I think would be helpful for my situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-to-resolve-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: The link I posted in previous comment was to one of the answers of that question :-). Helpful stuff! I am new to this particular way of using git, as you can tell. I think sometimes one doesn't know quite what question one is asking, until one asks it... I think a more friendly way of navigating merge conflicts is a big part of the answer I was looking for, and I have got that answer now I think.

Comment: If one of the answers there solved your problem, please accept the duplicate nomination.

Comment: The other part of the question is specific to eleventy, and I suppose I'm wondering if updating my fork from upstream is actually of any use; does it give me anything significant beyond what doing `npm update` in the eleventy folder gives me anyway.