# Github - Discard all changes

Tags: git, github, jmeter

I have an old fork in github which is left behind master on https://github.com/apache/jmeter

> This branch is 15740 commits ahead

How do I discard all my changes?

I tried also to pull using GitHub Desktop, but it doesn't make any difference

Also it seems that I can only rebase using my forked project and not the origin github project

**EDIT**

Tried using [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream) and failed

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/apache/jmeter.git

git fetch upstream

git checkout master
```

return error:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

if I continue ignoring the error then `push origin master --force` returns error:

```
src refspec master does not match any.
```

overcome command line error using different answer in using

```
git checkout -t -b master
```

But then last push failed

```
[remote rejected]       master -> master (permission denied) error: failed to push some refs
```

Comment: `git reset origin/master --hard`

Comment: Try `git reset --hard original/master`? Where original is the remote for the forked project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clean up a fork and restart it from the upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream)

Comment: @semisecure I executed `git reset origin/master --hard` but in github I still see changes

Comment: Did you execute the push command: `git push origin master --force `

Comment: @flaxel I want to override my changes, not push them

Comment: If you follow the instructions in the post above, you will reset your changes and update your fork.

Comment: @flaxel `git checkout master` return error:
`error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.` and then `push origin master --force` returns 
`error: src refspec master does not match any.`

Comment: Your default branch will probably be `main` instead of `master`.

Comment: @flaxel same for `main`, I'm forking `https://github.com/apache/jmeter`

Comment: Did you execute the `git fetch` command?

Comment: @flaxel yes, follow the commands in order

Comment: Hmmm... If you don't need your local changes any more anyway, you can delete your fork and create a new one, right?

Comment: @flaxel how to delete my fork?

Comment: You can go to your repo > Settings > Delete this repository.

Comment: @flaxel I don't have delete option in Settings , can you add answer with screenshot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646167/clean-up-a-fork-and-restart-it-from-the-upstream) doesn't work and you don't need the changes anymore, you can also [delete your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/deleting-a-repository). To do this, go to the `Settings` tab in your repository. You will find the button `Delete this repository` at the bottom:

[image: github danger zone]

A new fork can then be created.

Comment: Are you using GitHub Desktop? I don't see delete option

Comment: I am directly on github.com. Did it work for you?

Comment: Upvoted, but I hope there is a better way to simply rebase from master without getting into this danger zone ( removing all my previous project changes)

Comment: Yes definitely. :D It's funny, but it's nice that you were able to solve the problem first. I will take a look at the evening if I find the mistake.

Comment: overcome command line error using answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn using `git checkout -t -b master` , but then last push failed `[remote rejected]       master -> master (permission denied) error: failed to push some refs`

Comment: Have you configured your branch from the fork as a protected branch? Is that the complete error? What do you get as output for the command: `git remote -v`?